# Sender pid is zero when receiving SIGINT via CTRL-C

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

In my signal handler which is setup via `sigaction()` using the `SA_SIGINFO` flag  the `si_pid` member (which stores the sending process ID) of the `siginfo_t` struct is zero when `SIGINT` is triggered via `CTRL-C`

Take the following example which uses `signalfd()` for simplicity in order to demonstrate the "issue":

```
#include <sys/signalfd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        sigset_t mask;
        int sfd;
        struct signalfd_siginfo fdsi;
        ssize_t s;

        printf("my process id: %d\n", getpid());

        sigemptyset(&mask);
        sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);

        /* block signals to avoid default handling */
        if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1) {
                perror("sigprocmask");
                return 1;
        }

        sfd = signalfd(-1, &mask, 0);
        if (sfd == -1) {
                perror("signalfd");
                return 1;
        }

        printf("waiting for sigint ...\n");

        /* raise(SIGINT); */

        s = read(sfd, &fdsi, sizeof(struct signalfd_siginfo));
        if (s != sizeof(struct signalfd_siginfo)) {
                perror("reading from signal fd");
                return 1;
        }

        if (fdsi.ssi_signo != SIGINT) {
                fprintf(stderr, "received unexpected signal %d\n", fdsi.ssi_signo);
                return 1;
        }

        printf("received SIGINT from process %d\n", fdsi.ssi_pid);

        return 0;
}
```

If you run this program and trigger a `kill -INT pid` from another tty the output of the program is:

```
my process id: 23540
waiting for sigint ...
received SIGINT from process 23186
```

Now, if you press `CTRL-C` after starting the program the output is:

```
my process id: 23551
waiting for sigint ...
^Creceived SIGINT from process 0
```

If I raise SIGINT in the program (by uncommenting the line `/* raise(SIGINT); */` in the code sample) the output is:

```
my process id: 23577
waiting for sigint ...
received SIGINT from process 23577
```

Now if I enabled the linux [ftrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftrace) syscall tracers for `kill`, `tkill` and `tgkill` I can verify that the signal is handled by the `sys_kill` in the first example and by `sys_tgkill` in the last example.

However, none of these system calls is invoked when pressing `CTRL-C`.

Questions:
Which (if any) system call is invoked when `CTRL-C` is pressed ?
Who is passing the instruction pointer to the syscall handler on `CTRL-C` ?
Why is the sender pid in the  `siginfo_t` struct zero on `CTRL-C` (bug or documented feature) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No system calls get invoked, by any process, when `SIGINT` gets sent as a result of `CTRL-C` getting pressed. That's why the sender's PID is zero.

The signal gets sent from the kernel. Specifically, the TTY module. Each process is (optionally) tied to a terminal, the "controlling terminal". Each terminal has a defined key sequence that generates a `SIGINT` to all processes that are tied to the terminal. The default key sequence is, of course, `CTRL-C`.

You can think of PID 0 as the "kernel process", in this instance.

Reference:

- The [stty(1)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/stty.1.html) manual page.

See if you can spot `CTRL-C` in stty's output:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -extproc
```

- See also the "NOTES" section of the [setpgid(2)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/setpgid.2.html) manual page for more information on controlling terminals.

Comment: Awesome! That explains everything. The kernel part responsible for sending the signal is here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c?v=3.19#L1124